# Dividing two COUNTS from mysql

Tags: mysql

Friends, I am trying to divide two COUNT(*) from MySQL:
I have this query:

```
SELECT 'Total ', COUNT(*) 
FROM root4 
WHERE str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE()  
UNION 
SELECT  'Good', COUNT(*) 
FROM root4 
WHERE str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE() 
AND testresult ='OK'
```

The output of this query is looking like this:

```
________________________
|Total | COUNT(*) |
________________________
|Total| 42       | 
|Good | 34       | 
_______________________
```

What I want to achieve is to make another row under "Good" called "FPY" but the value to the dividing of "Good" to "Total" in percentage.
Something like this:

```
________________________
|Total | COUNT(*) |
________________________
|Total| 42       | 
|Good | 34       | 
|FPY  | 80.95    |
_______________________
```

I tried to divide them like noob:

```
SELECT 'Total ', COUNT(*) 
FROM root4 
WHERE str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE()  
UNION 
SELECT  'Good', COUNT(*) 
FROM root4 WHERE str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE() 
AND testresult ='OK'                         
UNION 
SELECT 'FPY',  (COUNT(*) 
FROM root4 
WHERE str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE() / 
UNION 
SELECT  'Good', COUNT(*) 
FROM root4 
WHERE str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE() 
AND testresult ='OK')
```

Of course, this is not working...

Note: Colum `DATE` is varchar that`s why I am using str_to_date.

Comment: If we can read the query, maybe we can help. Its easier to read if its all on the page and we dont have to scroll right into tomorrow

Comment: Brackets are wrong in the 3rd query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
       SUM(testresult ='OK') AS Good,
       100 * COUNT(*) / SUM(testresult ='OK') AS FPY
FROM root4 
WHERE `date` = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

---

> is there any way to print it in two columns as I post in the question? – Azim Feta

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total,
           SUM(testresult ='OK') AS Good
    FROM root4 
    WHERE `date` = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%d.%m.%Y')
    )
SELECT 'Total' AS indicator, Total AS value FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Good', Good FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FPY', 100 * Good / Total FROM cte
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working but is there any way to print it in two columns as I post in the question?

Comment: @AzimFeta Use this query as CTE, and a query with 2 UNION ALL based on this CTE.

Comment: Apologies Akina, I did not get it how exactly :(

Comment: Akina, this is working great. God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could be needing a "[SubQuery](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/)" here.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Count(root4.*) AS Total,
    root4_1.Good AS Good,
    COUNT(root4.*) / root4_1.Good AS FYP
FROM 
    root4,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*) AS Good
        FROM 
            root4 
        WHERE 
            str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE() 
        AND 
            testresult ='OK'  
    )AS root4_1 
WHERE 
    str_to_date(DATE, '%d.%m.%Y') = CURDATE()
```

Also, see this question, which is similar: [How to SELECT based on value of another SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970495/how-to-select-based-on-value-of-another-select)

Comment: Thank you. This is giving me an SQL Syntax error near '*) AS...
If I replace (*) with some column: 
FUNCTION root4.count does not exist.
I am really new to this and any help is highly appreciated

Comment: @AzimFeta Sorry, that's an oversight from me - I've specified the table name outside the COUNT, when count is an aggregate function.  See my updated answer, which should solve that issue