# Fill-in missing data in MySQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariasql

I want to present information from a MySQL DB (MariaDB, actually) approximately as follows:

```
SELECT Client, Year, SUM(Sales) 
FROM MySalesTable 
GROUP BY Client, Year 
ORDER BY Client, Year DESC
```

The issue is, if there is no data for a particular year for the client, MySQL entirely skips the rows, while I'd like the table to include all years in a range (say: 2015-2022) for all the clients - filled with zeros, nulls, or empty strings.

Normally, I would left-JOIN the query to a table containing bare year numbers (or filter years from a table which includes calendar information of any sort) but I do not have it at hand. I know that I can create a TEMPORARY table and populate it accordingly - but is it possible to create a transient 'pseudotable' on the fly as a subquery? Something like in the pseudocode:

`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT Year FROM [2015, 2016,...2022]) LEFT JOIN ....`

Thank you very much upfront.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you really need to do this in MySQL? Why not do this in your application?

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a `LEFT JOIN` between:

- the combination of each client with every year
- your query

then apply the `COALESCE` function on the missing Sales.

```
WITH combinations AS (
    SELECT clients.Client, years.Year
    FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT Client FROM MySalesTable) clients
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Year FROM MySalesTable) years ON 1=1
) 
SELECT Client,
       Year,
       COALESCE(total_sales, 0) AS total_sales
FROM      combinations
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Client, Year, SUM(Sales) AS total_sales
           FROM MySalesTable 
           GROUP BY Client, Year) sales
       ON combinations.Client = sales.Client 
      AND combinations.Year = sales.Year
ORDER BY Client, Year DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution, although very innefficient, would be to get a list of the years from years from the same table.....

```
SELECT a.client, allyears.year, sum(a.sales) 
FROM mysalestable
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM MySalesTable) allyears 
LEFT JOIN MySalesTable a
ON allyears.year=a.year
....
```

However this will still not list clients with no sales in a year - really you need a data source producing a list of all years and all clients - that needs a cartesian join....

```
SELECT allclients.client, allyears.year, sum(a.sales) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM MySalesTable) allyears
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT client FROM MySalesTable) allclients 
LEFT JOIN MySalesTable a
ON allyears.year=a.year
AND allclients.client=a.client
GROUP BY allclients.client, allyears.year
ORDER BY allclients.client, allyears.year DESC
```

(You may have other tables which are less expensive to query for allyears and all clients)

Unfortunately MySQL does not have a mechanism for implementing a [row generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701444/how-do-i-make-a-row-generator-in-mysql).

Answer (score -1):

I think this can be helpfull to you:

[How to SELECT based on value of another SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970495/how-to-select-based-on-value-of-another-select)

```
select t1.*, t2.* from (
SELECT Client, Year, SUM(Sales) FROM MySalesTable GROUP BY Client, Year
) as t1,
(
SELECT Client, Year, SUM(Sales) FROM MySalesTable GROUP BY Client, Year
) as t2
where t1.Client = t2.Client
```

even you can inner join tables